# What is the minimum IOS version for [UIImageView centerXAnchor]?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout

Can someone tell me what the minimum IOS version is for `[UIImageView centerXAnchor]` I have been looking around and can't find the information. I keep receiving the following error when testing on IOS 8.1.

```
-[UIImageView centerXAnchor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ab46b10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Available in iOS 9 and later.

For future reference, you can check this by **Option + Left Click**, on the method name.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information, I was not aware of that option.

Answer (score 1):

Available in iOS 9.0 and later.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILayoutGuide_Class_Reference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILayoutGuide/centerXAnchor

Answer (score 1):

This is the apple define  `@property(readonly, strong) NSLayoutXAxisAnchor *centerXAnchor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);` ,  it means Available in iOS 9.0 and later.
hope it help.